# Integration Kafka 0.10.x (or higher) in Spark 1.6.0 CDH 5.14.2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming, cloudera

I'm trying to use Kafka 0.10.2 in my Spark Streaming project (that uses 1.6.0-cdh.5.14.2 library), but it throws the following error at runtime:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILkafka/message/Message;JLkafka/serializer/Decoder;Lkafka/serializer/Decoder;)V
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext
```

In particular, it happens when I use foreachPartition on a specific RDD.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the Spark Kafka jar from? Please show how you run the Spark app

Comment: I get the library from spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 and kafka_2.10 with version 0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0. I create the inputDStream then i call:

stream.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
rdd.foreachPartition{iter =>
        iter.foreach(msg => println(msg._2))
    }
}

the inner foreach throws the error.